# MS Access select the most recent date for each GroupID

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have three MS Access tables, tblGroup, tblItem, tblStatus:

```
[tblItem]
ItemID
ItemName
ItemDate
GroupID
StatusID

[tblGroup]
GroupName
StatusID

[tblStatus]
StatusID
StatusName
```

I am trying to write a VBA SQL query to select all rows in tblItem with the most recent date (i.e. Max(ItemDate)) for each GroupID where the StatusID of tblGroup is equal to "1".

I have been trying variations of the following (see below) but I don't  understand how to filter the results based on another table i.e. where the StatusID of tblGroup is equal to "1" in another table.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmItem"
Forms!frmItem.frmItemSubform.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT tblItem.ItemID, Max(tblItem.ItemDate) FROM tblItem GROUP BY tblItem.ItemID, tblItem.ItemDate"
Forms!frmItem.frmItemSubform.Requery
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

George

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding correctly, then this is almost a direct translation of your requirements:

```
select i.*
from tblItem as i 
where i.date = (select max(i2.date)
                from tblItems as i2 inner join
                     tblGroup as g
                     on i2.GroupId = g.GroupId
                where i2.GroupId = i.GroupId and g.StatusId = 1
               );
```

Or, alternatively:

```
select i.*
from tblItem as i inner join
     (select i.GroupId, max(i2.date) as date
      from tblItems as i2 inner join
           tblGroup as g
           on i2.GroupId = g.GroupId
      where g.StatusId = 1
      group by GroupId
     ) gmax
     on gmax.GroupId = i.GroupId and gmax.date = i2.date;
```

These versions are not exactly the same.  The first might not work if there are ties for dates across groups for an item.  This fixes that problem.